# Stream contents of directory instead of reading all items

Tags: directory, tail, streaming, head

Is there a unix command I can use to stream the items/contents of a directory? Using Node.js, we can read everything into memory with:

```
fs.readdir(dir, (err, items) => {});
```

but I am looking to stream items, for a very large directory, say with more than 10 million folders/files in it.

The `tail` command is for reading files not folders TMK, so is there some unix utility that can stream the contents of folders?

Comment: I think you're just asking for the `find` command then. `find . -type f` will provide a stream of filenames which you can do do what you want with.

Comment: yes I guess `find` can stream results back, is there some way to fine-tune find so that it doesn't read too many items at once or whatever?

Comment: Yes, `find` does offer many options and tests to refine or narrow down the results; too many to mention here. Refer to the man page. BTW, it reads ALL directory entries, and then decides which of those to select and act upon / print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix you can use the `find` command to stream files & directories or both. The most basic command is this:

```
$ find .
```

This will stream a list of files & directories which can then be passed through to another command via a pipe, `|` or you can use `find`'s built in ability to run another command via `-exec`.

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep <somestring> {} \;
```

Or

```
$ find . -type f | ....
```

If you just want the contents of a single directory you can restrict find via the `-depth` switch:

```
$ find . -type f -depth 1 | ....
```

Answer (score 2):

At the system level the `readdir(3)` call is used to return a stream of directory entries, until error or that list runs out:

```
 The readdir() function returns a pointer to the next directory entry in
 the named directory stream dirp.  It returns NULL upon reaching the end
 of the directory or detecting an invalid seekdir() operation.
```

Whether and how `fs.readdir` maps to the above will depend on how that function is implemented in JavaScript; there may be a way to call `fs.readdir` to obtain individual directory entries in turn and not read them all into memory at once.

`readdir(3)` is not recursive; it will not check the contents of child directories; for that the `fts(3)` call is typically used. Higher level languages may use `fts(3)` or they may instead manually recurse over successive `opendir`, `readdir`, and `closedir` calls for each new child directory found during the `readdir(3)` loop.

Specific high level language implementations may be inefficient for large numbers of files; I believe that the Go language has a concurrent filesystem recursing implementation, and that various fixes have been made over the years to implementations.